# How to check against Content name of the ListBoxItem?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpfdatagrid, listboxitem

I was able to toggle visibility of menuItem based on the property of another content (data in the datagrid). I need to be able to achieve the same with listbox items. I have hard time doing so. I am wondering if someone can help with that: Any help is highly appreciated!

The way it worked with menuItems:
XAML:

```
<SplitButton:MenuButton x:Name="test" Content="Test">
 <SplitButton:MenuButton.ButtonMenuItemsSource>
      <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="item1" Header="Item1" />
      <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="item1" Header="Item2" />
  </SplitButton:MenuButton.ButtonMenuItemsSource>
```

I have problem with setting the same var for lisboxitem listbox. It is working perfect with MenuItems.

```
var item1Task = test.ButtonMenuItemsSource.OfType<ListBoxItem>().Where(temp => temp.Name == "item1").First();
```

I need to convert this coede line of setting var in a way that it will work with ListBoxItem:

Listbox XAML:

```
<toolkit:Expander x:Name="test" Header="Test">
<Border x:Name="Border">
  <ListBox x:Name="List">
         <ListBoxItem x:Name="item1" Content="Item1" />
         <ListBoxItem x:Name="item2" Content="Item2" />
   </ListBox>
```

I cannot use OfType within listbox content. I tried something like that:

```
var item1Task = List.OfType<ListBoxItem>().Where(temp => temp.Content == "item1").First();
```

I hope it is possible. It is working great with the previous control, but I need to do the same using listbox. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to find ListBoxItem named "item1" or which has "item1" as Content? To do the first, you may try this query:

```
var item1Task = List.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>().First(temp => temp.Name == "item1");
```

If you need to find content, use this:

```
var item1Task = List.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>().First(temp => temp.Content == "Item1");
```

You should give more attention to case sensitivity when comparing strings. Also there is no need to use Where and First together, because First already has [conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) version.